# Font identification from 1950-1960

Tags: font-identification

Found this in Malmö, Sweden. It means Malmö Power Plant and is from late 50s och early 60s. I have big trouble identifiering the font, particular the R and the E with the lowered centers bar.[image]

Comment: It sure is a lovely time piece. I guess it's reasonable to assume it was created on-site - either with or without an existing example. Did you try any font recognition site, which may be able to find a digital font that is close enough? See also [What are the requirements for a font identification?](http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/1083/30216).

Comment: I tried various online font identifying pages but the closest was a Grotesk type but still the R and E don't match. But as you said it could be a local type.

Answer (score 2):

This type has the characteristics of the late 1940-50's follow up of Art Deco: Modernism. And there is a modern revival of such a font: House Industries' [**Neutraface**](http://www.houseind.com/fonts/neutraface). A design by Christian Schwartz heavily influenced by the work of architect Richard Neutra (whose father coincidentally owned a metal foundry, so it nicely ties in with your "industrial" look).

It even has the widely spaced umlaut – yet even larger than in your sample:

[image: Neutraface sample]

(sample courtesy of House Industries – [direct link](http://199.38.86.57/cgi-bin/ls?foundry=house&layout=NeutraDisplay-Medium&tb1=MALM%C3%96%20ELVERK&tf1=case.0&tf1=liga.0&tf1=calt.0&tf1=salt.0))

Comment: Thanks! This is almost right. The E are spot on but the R and M is a little bit of.

Comment: @Kim: As I said, I seriously doubt you'd find an **exact** match for a (likely) handmade text from a pre-digital age.